# Prove the following combinatorial identity.

Tags: combinatorics

Prove the following combinatorial identity:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m} = \sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}2^k,$$ where $n \ge m$.

Comment: What did you try ? What are your thoughts ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy Well... I tried to use the multinomial theorem but failed.

Comment: Please use the body of you Question to explain how you "tried to use the multinomial theorem".  The little that you wrote gives Readers no sense of your approach and suggests (in part by using an imperative sentence) that you intend others to do your thinking for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $ \binom{n+k}{m}= [x^m]:(1+x)^{n+k}$
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n+k}{m} &=&[x^m]: (1+x)^n \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} (1+x)^k \\
\\&=&[x^m]: (1+x)^n (2+x)^m \\&=& [x^m]: \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} 2^k x^{m-k}(1+x)^n \\&=& \sum_{k=0}^{m} \binom{m}{k} \binom{n}{k} 2^k 
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Question about notation: What is $[x^m]:(1+x)^{n+k}$?

Comment: @1524 The coefficient of $x^m$ in the function $(1+x)^{n+k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Show that both sides are equal to the coefficient of $t^m$ in the Taylor expansion of  $\frac{(1+t)^n}{(1-t)^{n+1}}$ at $t=0$, that is
$$\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n+k}{m} =[t^m]\frac{(1+t)^n}{(1-t)^{n+1}}=[t^m]\frac{1}{(1-t)}\left(1+\frac{2t}{1-t}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^{m}\binom{m}{k}\binom{n}{k}2^k.$$

Comment: really eleagnt +1